# Android getOrientation() method returns bad results

Tags: java, android, orientation

I'm creating 3D Compass application.

I'm using [getOrientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D%29) method to get orientation (almost same implementation like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963705/using-getrotationmatrix-and-getorientation-in-android-2-1)). If I place phone on the table it works well, but when top of the phone points to the sky (minus Z axis on the picture; sphere is the Earth) getOrientation starts giving really bad results. It gives values for Z axis between 0 to 180 degrees in a few real degrees. Is there any way how to suppress this behavior? I created a [little video](http://youtu.be/U1o5TsCKOd0) what describes problem (sorry for bad quality). Thanks in advance.

[image]

**Solution**:
When you rotating model, there is difference between:

```
gl.glRotatef(_angleY, 0f, 1f, 0f); //ROLL
gl.glRotatef(_angleX, 1f, 0f, 0f); //ELEVATION
gl.glRotatef(_angleZ, 0f, 0f, 1f); //AZIMUTH


gl.glRotatef(_angleX, 1f, 0f, 0f); //ELEVATION
gl.glRotatef(_angleY, 0f, 1f, 0f); //ROLL
gl.glRotatef(_angleZ, 0f, 0f, 1f); //AZIMUTH
```

Comment: (1) What is your sensor delay? (2) Are you doing any low pass filtering on your data?

Comment: 1. Delay is set to Fastest (both, accelerometer and magnetic field sensor)
2. I have a circular buffer and I compute average value of last ten incoming values. After changing buffer size to 1, problem is still there, but model oscillate much more.

Comment: Hi, could you send your apk again? The version you included on your post is not properly decoded as .apk by Android on both my phone and my tablet...

Comment: I have uploaded it again, same adress. Still same problem?

Comment: Hi Skywall. Please see my reply to your comment on my post concerning range [0, 360[ vs [-180, 180[, as it does affect the outcome of the IIR filter algorithm adversely. As for the .apk, yes still same problem, hope it's not just me... I'm on android 2.1 only with my HTC phone...

Comment: Hi again Skywall. As I could not load your .apk still, I implemented my own version of a Compass3D. See the entire code below. It worked OK on my own phone, so perhaps you could test on your phone to see if it behaves as expected... This might clear up whether it is something else (hardware problem) or truly an issue with the code itself...

Comment: Glad that my code helped, friend :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, I can see at least 1 problem with this approach of yours.

I assume that you combine a 3D vector corresponding to your magnetometer with an averaging low pass filter to smoothen the data. Although such approach would work great for a sensor value which varies without discontinuities, such as raw data from accelerometer, it doesn't work so great verbatim with angular variables fetched from your magnetometer. Why, one might ask?

Because those angular variables (azimuth, pitch, roll) have an upper-bound and a lower-bound, which means that any value above 180 degrees, say 181 degrees, would wrap around to 181-360 = -179 degrees, and any variable below -180 degrees would wrap around in the other direction. So when one of those angular variables get close to those thresholds (180 or -180), this variable will tend to oscillate to values close to those 2 extremes. When you blindly apply a low-pass filter to those values, you get either a smooth decreasing from 180 degrees towards -180 degrees, or a smooth increasing from -180 towards 180 degrees. Either way, the result would look quite like your video above... As long as one directly applies an averaging buffer onto the raw angle data from `getOrientation(...)`, this problem will be present (and should be present not only for the case where the phone is upright, but also in the cases where there are azimuth angle wraparounds too... Maybe you could test for those bugs as well...).

You say that you tested this with a buffer size of 1. Theoretically, the problem should not be present if there is no averaging at all, although in some implementations of a circular buffer I've seen in the past, it could mean that there is still averaging done with at least 1 past value, not that there is no averaging at all. If this is your case, we have found the root cause of your bug.

Unfortunately, there isn't much of an elegant solution that could be implemented while sticking with your standard averaging filter. What I usually do in this case is switch to another type of low pass filter, which doesn't need any deep buffer to operate: a simple IIR filter (order 1):

*diff = x[n] - y[n-1]*

*y[n] - y[n-1] = alpha* * *(x[n] - y[n-1]) = alpha* * *diff*

...where *y* is the filtered angle, *x* is the raw angle, and *alpha*<1 is analogous to a time constant, as alpha=1 corresponds to the no-filter case, and the frequency cutoff of the low-pass filter gets lowered as alpha approaches zero. An acute eye would probably have noticed by now that this corresponds to a simple *Proportional Controller*.

Such a filter allows the compensation of the wraparound of the angle value because we can add or subtract 360 to *diff* so as to ensure that *abs(diff)<=180*, which in turn ensures that the filtered angle value will always increase/decrease in the optimal direction to reach its "setpoint".

An example function call, which is to be scheduled periodically, that calculates a filtered angle value y for a given raw angle value x, could be something like this:

```
private float restrictAngle(float tmpAngle){
    while(tmpAngle>=180) tmpAngle-=360;
    while(tmpAngle<-180) tmpAngle+=360;
    return tmpAngle;
}

//x is a raw angle value from getOrientation(...)
//y is the current filtered angle value
private float calculateFilteredAngle(float x, float y){ 
    final float alpha = 0.1f;
    float diff = x-y;

    //here, we ensure that abs(diff)<=180
    diff = restrictAngle(diff);

    y += alpha*diff;
    //ensure that y stays within [-180, 180[ bounds
    y = restrictAngle(y);

    return y;
}
```

The function `calculateFilteredAngle(float x, float y)` can then be called periodically using something like this (example for azimuth angle from `getOrientation(...)` function:

```
filteredAzimuth = calculateFilteredAngle(azimuth, filteredAzimuth);
```

Using this method, the filter would not misbehave like the averaging filter as mentioned by the OP.

As I could not load the .apk uploaded by the OP, I decided to implement my own test project in order to see if the corrections work. Here is the entire code (it does not use a .XML for the main layout, so I did not include it). Simply copy it to a test project to see if it works on a specific device (tested functional on a HTC Desire w/ Android v. 2.1):

File 1: Compass3DActivity.java:

```
package com.epichorns.compass3D;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Compass3DActivity extends Activity {
    //Textviews for showing angle data
    TextView mTextView_azimuth;
    TextView mTextView_pitch;
    TextView mTextView_roll;

    TextView mTextView_filtered_azimuth;
    TextView mTextView_filtered_pitch;
    TextView mTextView_filtered_roll;


    float mAngle0_azimuth=0;
    float mAngle1_pitch=0;
    float mAngle2_roll=0;

    float mAngle0_filtered_azimuth=0;
    float mAngle1_filtered_pitch=0;
    float mAngle2_filtered_roll=0;

    private Compass3DView mCompassView;

    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    //sensor calculation values
    float[] mGravity = null;
    float[] mGeomagnetic = null;
    float Rmat[] = new float[9];
    float Imat[] = new float[9];
    float orientation[] = new float[3];
    SensorEventListener mAccelerometerListener = new SensorEventListener(){
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {}

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
                mGravity = event.values.clone();
                processSensorData();
            }
        }   
    };
    SensorEventListener mMagnetometerListener = new SensorEventListener(){
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {}

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD){
                mGeomagnetic = event.values.clone();
                processSensorData();                
                update();
            }
        }   
    };

    private float restrictAngle(float tmpAngle){
        while(tmpAngle>=180) tmpAngle-=360;
        while(tmpAngle<-180) tmpAngle+=360;
        return tmpAngle;
    }

    //x is a raw angle value from getOrientation(...)
    //y is the current filtered angle value
    private float calculateFilteredAngle(float x, float y){ 
        final float alpha = 0.3f;
        float diff = x-y;

        //here, we ensure that abs(diff)<=180
        diff = restrictAngle(diff);

        y += alpha*diff;
        //ensure that y stays within [-180, 180[ bounds
        y = restrictAngle(y);

        return y;
    }



    public void processSensorData(){
        if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) { 
            boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(Rmat, Imat, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
            if (success) {              
                SensorManager.getOrientation(Rmat, orientation);
                mAngle0_azimuth = (float)Math.toDegrees((double)orientation[0]); // orientation contains: azimut, pitch and roll
                mAngle1_pitch = (float)Math.toDegrees((double)orientation[1]); //pitch
                mAngle2_roll = -(float)Math.toDegrees((double)orientation[2]); //roll               
                mAngle0_filtered_azimuth = calculateFilteredAngle(mAngle0_azimuth, mAngle0_filtered_azimuth);
                mAngle1_filtered_pitch = calculateFilteredAngle(mAngle1_pitch, mAngle1_filtered_pitch);
                mAngle2_filtered_roll = calculateFilteredAngle(mAngle2_roll, mAngle2_filtered_roll);    
            }           
            mGravity=null; //oblige full new refresh
            mGeomagnetic=null; //oblige full new refresh
        }
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);       
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);      
        ll.setLayoutParams(llParams);      
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);      
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams txtParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);        
        mTextView_azimuth = new TextView(this);
        mTextView_azimuth.setLayoutParams(txtParams);
        mTextView_pitch = new TextView(this);
        mTextView_pitch.setLayoutParams(txtParams);
        mTextView_roll = new TextView(this);
        mTextView_roll.setLayoutParams(txtParams);      
        mTextView_filtered_azimuth = new TextView(this);
        mTextView_filtered_azimuth.setLayoutParams(txtParams);
        mTextView_filtered_pitch = new TextView(this);
        mTextView_filtered_pitch.setLayoutParams(txtParams);
        mTextView_filtered_roll = new TextView(this);
        mTextView_filtered_roll.setLayoutParams(txtParams);

        mCompassView = new Compass3DView(this);        
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams compassParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(200,200);
        mCompassView.setLayoutParams(compassParams);

        ll.addView(mCompassView);
        ll.addView(mTextView_azimuth);
        ll.addView(mTextView_pitch);
        ll.addView(mTextView_roll);
        ll.addView(mTextView_filtered_azimuth);
        ll.addView(mTextView_filtered_pitch);
        ll.addView(mTextView_filtered_roll);

        setContentView(ll);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(mAccelerometerListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI); 
        sensorManager.registerListener(mMagnetometerListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        update();       
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(mAccelerometerListener);
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(mMagnetometerListener);
    }


    private void update(){
        mCompassView.changeAngles(mAngle1_filtered_pitch,  mAngle2_filtered_roll, mAngle0_filtered_azimuth);

        mTextView_azimuth.setText("Azimuth: "+String.valueOf(mAngle0_azimuth));
        mTextView_pitch.setText("Pitch: "+String.valueOf(mAngle1_pitch));
        mTextView_roll.setText("Roll: "+String.valueOf(mAngle2_roll));

        mTextView_filtered_azimuth.setText("Azimuth: "+String.valueOf(mAngle0_filtered_azimuth));
        mTextView_filtered_pitch.setText("Pitch: "+String.valueOf(mAngle1_filtered_pitch));
        mTextView_filtered_roll.setText("Roll: "+String.valueOf(mAngle2_filtered_roll));

    }
}
```

File 2: Compass3DView.java:

```
package com.epichorns.compass3D;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;

public class Compass3DView extends GLSurfaceView {
    private Compass3DRenderer mRenderer;

    public Compass3DView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mRenderer = new Compass3DRenderer(context);
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
    }

    public void changeAngles(float angle0, float angle1, float angle2){
        mRenderer.setAngleX(angle0);
        mRenderer.setAngleY(angle1);
        mRenderer.setAngleZ(angle2);
    }

}
```

File 3: Compass3DRenderer.java:

```
package com.epichorns.compass3D;


import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;


public class Compass3DRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    Context mContext;

    // a raw buffer to hold indices
    ShortBuffer _indexBuffer;    
    // raw buffers to hold the vertices
    FloatBuffer _vertexBuffer0;
    FloatBuffer _vertexBuffer1;
    FloatBuffer _vertexBuffer2;
    FloatBuffer _vertexBuffer3;
    FloatBuffer _vertexBuffer4;
    FloatBuffer _vertexBuffer5;
    int _numVertices = 3; //standard triangle vertices = 3

    FloatBuffer _textureBuffer0123;



    //private FloatBuffer _light0Position;
    //private FloatBuffer _light0Ambient;
    float _light0Position[] = new float[]{10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f};
    float _light0Ambient[] = new float[]{0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f, 1.0f};
    float _light0Diffuse[] = new float[]{0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f};
    float _light0Specular[] = new float[]{0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f};
    float _matAmbient[] = new float[] { 0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f, 1.0f };
    float _matDiffuse[] = new float[] { 0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f, 1.0f };




    private float _angleX=0f;
    private float _angleY=0f;
    private float _angleZ=0f;


    Compass3DRenderer(Context context){
        super();
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void setAngleX(float angle) {
        _angleX = angle;
    }

    public void setAngleY(float angle) {
        _angleY = angle;
    }

    public void setAngleZ(float angle) {
        _angleZ = angle;
    }

    FloatBuffer InitFloatBuffer(float[] src){
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*src.length);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        FloatBuffer inBuf = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        inBuf.put(src);
        return inBuf;
    }

    ShortBuffer InitShortBuffer(short[] src){
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(2*src.length);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        ShortBuffer inBuf = bb.asShortBuffer();
        inBuf.put(src);
        return inBuf;
    }

    //Init data for our rendered pyramid
    private void initTriangles() {

        //Side faces triangles
        float[] coords = {
            -0.25f, -0.5f, 0.25f,
            0.25f, -0.5f, 0.25f,
            0f, 0.5f, 0f
        };

        float[] coords1 = {
            0.25f, -0.5f, 0.25f,
            0.25f, -0.5f, -0.25f,
            0f, 0.5f, 0f
        };

        float[] coords2 = {
            0.25f, -0.5f, -0.25f,
            -0.25f, -0.5f, -0.25f,
            0f, 0.5f, 0f
        };

        float[] coords3 = {
            -0.25f, -0.5f, -0.25f,
            -0.25f, -0.5f, 0.25f,
            0f, 0.5f, 0f
        };

        //Base triangles
        float[] coords4 = {
            -0.25f, -0.5f, 0.25f,
            0.25f, -0.5f, -0.25f,
            0.25f, -0.5f, 0.25f
        };

        float[] coords5 = {
            -0.25f, -0.5f, 0.25f,
            -0.25f, -0.5f, -0.25f, 
            0.25f, -0.5f, -0.25f
        };


        float[] textures0123 = {
                // Mapping coordinates for the vertices (UV mapping CW)
                0.0f, 0.0f,     // bottom left                    
                1.0f, 0.0f,     // bottom right
                0.5f, 1.0f,     // top ctr              
        };


        _vertexBuffer0 = InitFloatBuffer(coords);
        _vertexBuffer0.position(0);

        _vertexBuffer1 = InitFloatBuffer(coords1);
        _vertexBuffer1.position(0);    

        _vertexBuffer2 = InitFloatBuffer(coords2);
        _vertexBuffer2.position(0);

        _vertexBuffer3 = InitFloatBuffer(coords3);
        _vertexBuffer3.position(0);

        _vertexBuffer4 = InitFloatBuffer(coords4);
        _vertexBuffer4.position(0);

        _vertexBuffer5 = InitFloatBuffer(coords5);
        _vertexBuffer5.position(0);

        _textureBuffer0123 = InitFloatBuffer(textures0123);
        _textureBuffer0123.position(0);

        short[] indices = {0, 1, 2};
        _indexBuffer = InitShortBuffer(indices);        
        _indexBuffer.position(0);

    }


    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE); // enable the differentiation of which side may be visible 
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);

        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW); // which is the front? the one which is drawn counter clockwise
        gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK); // which one should NOT be drawn

        initTriangles();

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {


        gl.glPushMatrix();

        gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0f); //clipping backdrop color
        // clear the color buffer to show the ClearColor we called above...
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // set rotation       
        gl.glRotatef(_angleY, 0f, 1f, 0f); //ROLL
        gl.glRotatef(_angleX, 1f, 0f, 0f); //ELEVATION
        gl.glRotatef(_angleZ, 0f, 0f, 1f); //AZIMUTH

        //Draw our pyramid

        //4 side faces
        gl.glColor4f(0.5f, 0f, 0f, 0.5f);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, _vertexBuffer0);
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, _numVertices, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, _indexBuffer);

        gl.glColor4f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0f, 0.5f);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, _vertexBuffer1);
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, _numVertices, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, _indexBuffer);

        gl.glColor4f(0f, 0.5f, 0f, 0.5f);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, _vertexBuffer2);
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, _numVertices, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, _indexBuffer);

        gl.glColor4f(0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, _vertexBuffer3);
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, _numVertices, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, _indexBuffer);

        //Base face
        gl.glColor4f(0f, 0f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, _vertexBuffer4);
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, _numVertices, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, _indexBuffer);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, _vertexBuffer5);
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, _numVertices, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, _indexBuffer);

        gl.glPopMatrix();
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    }



}
```

Please note that this code does not compensate for tablet default landscape orientation, so it is only expected to work correctly on a phone (I didn't have a tablet close by to test any correction code).

Comment: First of all, thanks for great answer. 1. I already solved `180 & -180` problem with transforming values between 160 & -160 to values 160 & 200. I used formula `new_angle = (old_angle+360)%360`. 2. I'll try your IIR filter, look really good. Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Yes, but I do have to mention that in order for this problem to go away, *diff* must be between [-180, 180[, not [0, 360[, which your formula doesn't provide. So if you add something like `if(new_angle>=180) new_angle-=360` it should be ok. The thing is that using 0-360 range for *diff* will result in a filter behavior that will not use optimal pathing to reach its desired destination. This means that near to your 360 angle threshold, when *diff* might jump back and forth from 0 to 360, you will get the same problem, hence the need for a [-180, 180[ angle limitation for *diff*.

Comment: Apologies for a (somewhat) lack of completeness in my previous comment: actually if *diff* is between  [0, 360[, problems will arise all along the range of your angle, since it will only allow your filtered angle to increase monotonically! It still does imply that when you transition from *diff* = 0 to *diff* = 360 there will be an undesirable jump, though...

Comment: So, did you try my approach yet? Did it change anything?

Comment: So, preview is much smoother, but problem is not solved at all.

Comment: Updated my answer with new code. Maybe you can test it with your own device to see if it behaves correctly...

Comment: Man, please take all my bounty :-D I try throw out my computing core and place there yours, but I was getting still same results. So I was started looking in renderer and I figured out, where was problem. See my first post.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably try a longer delay like Game and/or keep/increase the size of your circular buffer. The sensors (accelerometer, compass, etc.) on mobile devices are inherently noisy so when I asked about 'low pass filter', I meant do you use more data to decrease the frequency of your app usable updates. Your video was done inside, I would also recommend going to a place with less EM interference such as a park just to check that the behavior is consistent as well as the standard compass reset action (rotate device in figure-8). In the end you may have to apply some heuristics to throw out the 'bad' data to make a smoother experience for the user.

Comment: 1. Game Delay - same problem
2. Changing size of buffer - same problem
3. park - still same :(

Answer (score 1):

Well I had exactly the same problem as I was retrieving orientation. Thing is that I didn't get is solved (I had to set a constraint when it comes to the device position when retrieving it), and I don't know if you'll ever be able to.

Pick a magnetical compass and try to get north orientation when the compass is in the situation you describe - you will get the same non-sense results. So you can't really expect the device's compass to do it any better !

Comment: Yes, but in the vast majority of devices on the market, the magnetometer is a 3-axis magnetometer, whereas a common magnetic compass basically "projects" the magnetic field vector onto its mechanical 2D plane POV...

Answer (score 0):

Few words about filtering, with your permissions.

1. I would suggest to do averaging on Magnetic Field Vector itself before turning it into angles.
2. It is wrong to do averaging/smoothing only on angles without use of some sort of magnitude. Angles themselves are not providing enough data to detect direction/heading/bearing. 
   Example: When you want to know average wind direction during the whole day you must use the strength of the wind, not just only angles. If you will average only angles you will get absolutely wrong wind direction. 
   As for bearing direction I would use the speed for magnitude.