# TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR, TYPE_ORIENTATION give different results that too with deviation

Tags: android, android-sensors, magnetometer, rotational-matrices, digital-compass

I have implemented listener for both Rotation Vector and Orientation Vector though i know it's depreciated i wanted to test both.

I know Rotation Vector is a fusion sensor & recommended but according to it the NORTH (**the value[0] returned by getOrientation(rotationMatrix,value) geaving bearing 0**) doesn't matches with NORTH from Orientation sensor.
I've also tallied from different apps from playstore, orientation sensor values seem to be more close to them.

**Moreover many times my azimuth value[0] from Rotation_Vector then getOrientation just shoots up and keep oscillating between -180 to 180**

P.S "getRotationMatrix(float[] R, float[] I, float[] gravity, float[] geomagnetic)" also gives same result as Rotation Vector.

```
 public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
{
   float rotationMatrix[];      
  switch(event.sensor.getType())
  {  
   .
       .
       .       
  case Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR:
       rotationMatrix=new float[16];
       mSensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix,event.values);
       determineOrientation(rotationMatrix);
       break; 

   case Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION:
        sensorZValue.setText(""+event.values[0]); //rotation about geographical z axis  
        sensorXValue.setText(""+event.values[1]); //rotation about geographical x axis  
        sensorYValue.setText(""+event.values[2]); //rotation about geographical y axis

 }//switch case ends
}


private void determineOrientation(float[] rotationMatrix)
    {
    float[] orientationValues = new float[3];
    SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, orientationValues);
    double azimuth = Math.toDegrees(orientationValues[0]);
    double pitch = Math.toDegrees(orientationValues[1]);
    double roll = Math.toDegrees(orientationValues[2]);

    sensorZValue.setText(String.valueOf(azimuth));  //rotation about geographical z axis
    sensorXValue.setText(String.valueOf(pitch)); //rotation about geographical x axis   
    sensorYValue.setText(String.valueOf(roll)); //rotation about geographical y axis


    }
```

I want to **determine the angle between phone's Y axis and the Vector pointing North** so that was my initial implementation.
Please suggest.

Comment: According to android documentation values[1] points to North. So - pitch points to North, not azimuth :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think this will help...

[Android Compass that can Compensate for Tilt and Pitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317599/android-compass-that-can-compensate-for-tilt-and-pitch/16386066#16386066)

This calculates North using more reliable sources.

Hope this helps.